# executing the method once before first request to blueprint

Tags: python, flask

I am developing an intake form which contains child registration information.Is there a way to execute a method before a request to a blue print just once so that I can generate a key and store all the data of a child in the session object backed by redis associating with the key

Below code execute every time a request comes in thus generating a new key on every request

```
@child.before_request
def return_key():
    logger.info("IN RETURN KEY FUNCTION")
    return f"{random.randint(12457, 999998)}"
```

I want to do something like below

```
session[key] = <all child details>
```

The blueprint has different route like child names , child address , child information.The key should not change on these route so that a single key can be associated with all the data.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`before_first_request` method is what you are looking for:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request

Comment: Thank you.So right now I am running  the app on development server(one that comes in with flask).so the method on before_first_request decorator is getting called only once.Once I move this to a production grade server., will this method be called on every app request..like in a new tab or a new browser

Comment: `before_first_request` will be called when a new worker (process) of your production server will be created - within this worker, right before the first request.